# multi merchant site on same magento 2 installation

Tags: magento2, multi-website

I have 4 different clients who has the same requirement(modules/custom functionality) with different themes. I know we can achieve frontend using multi-website.

Can we have different admin logins with permission to access only their own website data(sales/product/category/discounts/etc)?

Are there any other restriction for going one magento + multi-website for different clients?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not a good option to go for multi-website for different clients even if it is possible. We can't create an admin user for a specific website/store. Also, the indexing process is common for all the websites in a multi-site setup so it will take time to complete. Also, If anyone of the site get attacked by the bot or something else, it will affect the other client site performance as well. Also, maybe in future client requirements may differ at that time it will make hard to maintain extensions. So, for different clients, I always recommend going with individual setup and avoid multi websites.

For the same clients, referer [Understanding websites, stores, and store views](https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/configure/configure-best-practices.html#sites) if needed please go with multi-website.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, Bilal. My concern is mainly because of admin. 
What if the requirement we are building doesn't change?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can. some separation features available in magento by default, some you can adjust with extensions, even separated filesystem and its own database, but.

this is all about security and maintenance complexity and as a result any issues affects reputation.

it is much easier to run 4 completely individual installations.

**update**

this is how managed hosting works. automate, snapshot, template.

control everything and manage with automation. as you have the same OS image for every container / instance you can easily track changes and updates with for example ansible or simple scripting from control unit. server configs are the same, customer only have their includes to adjust some parameters

magento versions and modules you can track the same with simple scan across all of your clients. they must have magento core and default code intact. also you can see how much they have overrides with simple scan (like for example magento debug extension do to find core overrides and conflicts)

for native composer modules you just upgrade with single command, with local modules you must keep your own repo to push with composer, etc.

Comment: Yes, we are hoping to have 30 more clients by end of this year as we are catering to specific market and the requirements won't change. My worry is managing with 4 different installation is that it will be very hard if we have 30+ different clients - upgrade and maintaining each of them will be very very time consuming. Suppose we do Magento upgrade + module upgrade every 2-3 months,

Comment: @Siva you need some deep automation and control, see update

Comment: thanks MagenX, I'm curious on what is the biggest complexity while maintaining one installation for every 10 clients or so?

Comment: everything, maintenance of separation, speed, and security. you need to be a pro to keep it up. or your 10 clients will suffer. if your clients know about it, you can look into markeplace extension with domain module.